# CSS - Odd issue with centering a div with percentages

Tags: html, css, margin, frontend

I'm building a fairly simple static frontend-only webpage. I have the following css rules for my wrapper div (everything else in the page is in it) and the body:

```
body {
  background-image: url(../img/background.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
}

#content_wrapper {
  margin: 15px 10%; /*Client wants 20% instead of 10. Navbar must be adjusted accordingly*/
  min-width: 900px;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;  
}
```

Which works fine:
[image: Webpage with 10% left and right margin]

However, as you can read by my comment the client prefers a 20% margin, as to make the whole page more narrow. However this happens:

[image: Webpage with 20% left and right margin]

The page shifts right. This is pretty much the same visual issue I have opening this page with my tablet even using 10% margin (although I would appreciate an explanation to why that happens in tablets, it's not the focus of this question here).
How can I fix this? For all I know this shouldn't happen

Comment: Margin should be auto on left/right to center. If you want to make the page narrow, adjust the WIDTH of the wrapper.

Comment: I thought of that, but wouldn't that imply changing all the other width values of the divs contained within it? Is there no way to simple change the margin?

Comment: Not if you want to center it. Is there a reason why you're using fixed widths for the interior content?

Comment: Yeah, trying to keep it consistent. Will upvote your comments and the explanation given below, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you state that

```
margin: 15px 20%;
```

you are effectively telling that you have `20%` for both of left and right `margin`. This means that `#content_wrapper` has `60%` of the container as a maximum. The problem is that `60%` might be bigger than the available space. I believe you should add the `width` to the rule:

```
width: 60%;
```

Comment: What I really wanted was an explanation to why this happens. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

well try changing it to `width: 15px 20% 15px 10%;`  you wish to change only left side margin to 10%.
Or put 2 blank `div` on each side of `.content-wrap` with 10% width and phantom data to give width to it

Comment: @Digriz, it happens because page sets 10% of the width as margin to the left and right side